# wordpress, custom menu is created but does not show up in the top head part in the admin panel

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My theme has several custom menus. I can manage them in the WP admin panel.

But look at the picture. You see 2 menus already created - Footer Menu and Header. But in my case those 2 names do not appear so I cannot do anything with them later.

Code I used:

```
add_action( 'init', 'menus_all' ); 

function menus_all() { register_nav_menus( array(

         'menu1' => _( 'menu1 loc'),

         'menu2' => _( 'menu2 loc'),
 ) ); }
```

How to make the menu names appear ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[**`register_nav_menu`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/register_nav_menu) goes straight in your `functions.php` file, without any hook:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'menu1' => _( 'menu1 loc'),
    'menu2' => _( 'menu2 loc'),
));
```

[image]

Comment: that does not solve the problem. There was a prob in the DB. Clicking on the `Browse` button in the Db table showed error. When that prob was solved, the mentioned problem also disappeared.

Comment: @b_ There were probs in the Db for which the tabs in phpmyadmin would show red errors. Hosting company solved it and the problem was gone.